# How to use protocol instead of delegate in iPhone

Tags: iphone, protocols

Scenario: Need to execute CustomWebview delegate on view controller.

Please help me with this code. Instead of using callback, I need to use  "Protocol". Can it be done or we can only use callback in this scenario.

**On ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //MyWebView *webView = [[MyWebView alloc] initWithDelegate:self callback:@selector(finishLoading)];

    MyWebView *webView= [[MyWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 460)];
    [webView LoadURL:@"http://192.168.5.165/"];
    [webView setDelegate:self];
    [webView setCallback:@selector(finishLoading)];
    [self.view addSubview:webView] ; 
}

- (void) finishLoading
{
    NSLog(@"Finish");
}
```

---

**On MyWebView.h**

```
@interface MyWebView : UIView<UIWebViewDelegate> {
    NSString *strURL;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *strURL;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) SEL callback;

-(void) LoadURL:(NSString*)url;
@end
```

**On MyWebView.m**

```
#import "MyWebView.h"

@implementation MyWebView
@synthesize strURL,delegate,callback;
UIWebView *webView;
-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if(self =[super initWithFrame:frame])
    {
        webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        webView.delegate = self;
        [self addSubview:webView];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void) LoadURL:(NSString*)url
{
    NSURL *u = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *req= [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:u];
    [webView loadRequest:req];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [delegate performSelector:callback];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit unclear. A protocol and a delegate are two entirely separate, though related, things--apples and oranges. A protocol defines a list of methods an object may or must respond to:

```
@protocol Document
+ (id)documentWithContentsOfURL: (NSURL *)aURL;
- (void)writeToURL: (NSURL *)aURL error: (NSError **)outError;
@end
```

A delegate is an object, usually an instance of a custom class, that is handed to another object for custom processing or feedback--that latter object *delegates* work to the delegate object.

---

Are you asking how to convert a delegate category on NSObject to a delegate protocol? (The former used to be Apple's pattern for defining the obligations and abilities of a delegate; the latter is the newer way to do the same thing.) If so, it generally looks something like this:

**Delegate Category on NSObject**

```
@interface NSObject (WidgetDelegate)
- (void)doSomethingWithWidget: (Widget *)w;
@end

@interface Widget : NSObject
@property (readwrite, assign) id delegate;
@end
```

**Delegate Protocol**

```
@protocol WidgetDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)doSomethingWithWidget: (Widget *)w;
@end


@interface Widget : NSObject
@property (readwrite, assign) id <WidgetDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

Is that what you're looking for? If not, can you clarify exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: I know the above code can have protocol, in that case I don't need to use CALLBACK. just don't know how to implement Protocol. Can you please help to change  the code by using Protocol instead of CALLBACK.

Comment: Do you mean you want your own class to have a delegate protocol (separate from `UIWebViewDelegate`)? If so, define the protocol (as shown above), change your delegate property's type from `id` to `id <PROTOCOL_NAME_HERE>`, and use either `[self.delegate performSelector: @selector(theDelegateMethod:) withObject: self]` or `objc_msgSend(self.delegate, @selector(theDelegateMethod:), self)` to send the message to the delegate. (If the protocol defines the method as optional, be sure to check that you can call it with `[self.delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(theDelegateMethod:)]` first!)

Comment: In MyWebView.h
@protocol webProtocol

- (void) loadWeb;

@end

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<webProtocol> delegate;. Now how do I implement this in "ViewControler.m"

Comment: You should consider reading Apple's Objective-C Primer. It explains this stuff. :) http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007594

Answer (score 0):

Also see Apple's [Communicating with Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html), which discusses delegates, protocols, and selectors. Though its listed under Mac OS X, most (if not all) appears to apply to iOS also.

Answer (score 0):

On ViewController.m

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<MyFinishLoadingDelegate> {
//your own definition
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //MyWebView *webView = [[MyWebView alloc] initWithDelegate:self callback:@selector(finishLoading)];

    MyWebView *webView= [[MyWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 460)];
    [webView LoadURL:@"http://192.168.5.165/"];
    [webView setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:webView] ; 
}

- (void)finishLoading //this is your implementation for MyFinishLoadingDelegate
{
    NSLog(@"Finish");
}
```

On MyWebView.h

```
//you declare the protocol here to tell anyone who'd like to act like your delegate that they need to implement "finishLoading"
@protocol MyFinishLoadingDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)finishLoading;
@end

@interface MyWebView : UIView<UIWebViewDelegate> {
    NSString *strURL;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *strURL;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MyFinishLoadingDelegate> delegate;

-(void) LoadURL:(NSString*)url;
@end
```

On MyWebView.m

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [delegate finishLoading];
}
```